# Not able to execute this program in Eclipse. If im able to execute it what are the changes needs to be done?

Tags: java

```
//This class defines person.
Class person {
    String name;
    int age;

    //This class calls method talk.
    void talk(){
        System.out.println("hello is:" +name);
        System.out.println("my age is :" +age);
    }
}
```

Comment: you need a main class to execute any program. you can either create a new class which creates a new person and then calls talk on this person or you just add a main method in you person class and do it all there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a main method. Java always seeks for a main method to run, the signature is always the same: `public static void main(String[] args);`

```
class person {

    String name;
    int age;

    public person(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    //This class calls method talk.

    public void talk(){
        System.out.println("hello is:" +name);
        System.out.println("my age is :" +age);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        person myperson = new person("foobar", 21);
        myperson.talk();
    }

}
```

Comment: The Code looks fine. But when im trying to compile your code i get the following error for the last line person.talk().cannot make static reference to the non static method talk() from the type person.

Comment: There is only a small thing, it needs to be myperson.talk().

Comment: Yeah sorry, just a typo

Comment: Mark as correct answer plz